# Predefine data in HTML field from XML in odoo

Tags: html, xml, odoo, odoo-14

I have a HTML-field in my `model.py` like this:

```
from odoo import models, fields

class TestModel(models.model):
    _name = 'test.model'
    content = fields.HTML()
```

To display the data of my model I used `<field name="content" widget='html'>` in the corresponding `view` file.
*Now I want to add predefined data, when the module is first installed.*

Normally, I add data inside the `data`folder with `.xml` files.
So I created an .xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="unique_id" model="test.model">
            <field name="content">
                <p>Some Text</p>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

But I end up getting parsing errors like this:

```
  File "/Path/to/my/odoo/installation/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 782, in convert_xml_import
    relaxng.assert_(doc)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3633, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_
    
AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: data, line 3
```

What am I doing wrong or do I have a complete wrong understanding of how the HTML-field works?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, if anyone ever stumbles across this...

One has to specify the type for an HTML-field.

So instead of `<field name="content">` it has to be `<field name="content" type="html">` and then it works as intended.

Happy Odoo'ing!